# getting correct window style as configured by windows shortcut

Tags: c#, .net

When you create a shortcut in windows to an application, in its properties you can define under "Run:" the initial window state (Minimized / Maximized / Normal).
C# applications do not, apparently, start up their forms according to this configuration out-of-the-box, so I figured I need to get this information somehow and write a code that does that programmatically on start up.
I cannot find a way to get this information in my c# application.
I have tried:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.WindowStyle
```

But for some reason this is always "Normal" regardless of the configuration in the file shortcut.

Does anyone have any idea how to come around this?

Answer (score 1):

Just made a quick test and it does work out-of-the-box only if your main form is set to start as Normal window state. If you choose Minimized or Maximized it will override the shortcut settings.

In case your main form is set as Normal you can detect the actual state using such code:

```
FormWindowState actualState = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].WindowState;
if (actualState != FormWindowState.Normal)
{
    //probably launched via shortcut overriding the state, handle.
}
```

Comment: Hi Shadow Wizard,
I'm not sure I understand your answer. My form is launched in a standard way from the main of a a static "Program" class, by calling:
`Application.Run(new Form1());`
Form1 is configured to launch in Normal state (and indeed always does, regardless of the configuration in the shortcut). I figured there must be a way to extract this configuration from somewhere and change the window state programmatically.

Comment: I can't reproduce the "and indeed always does, regardless of the configuration in the shortcut" part, if I choose to run Maximized in the shortcut, it indeed start maximized. I couldn't find any way to extract that information though.

Comment: OK, your response gave me an idea, and I further pin-pointed the problem. My form has "FormBorderStyle=None". If I change it to "Sizeable" it starts behaving correctly. Alas, I need this form to be without a border :-(
Would appreciate it if anyone has an idea how to solve this.

Comment: Weird, but whole different issue... better start new question for that. :)